# How can I remove the qed symbols from all lemma proofs?

Tags: amsmath, proofreading, proof-package

the following code will only make the qed not appear in the second proof. However, it it possible to make the qed symbol never appear at the end of the proofs without having to specify it locally every time?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
This has the QED symbol.
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}
This hasn't.
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
And this has it again.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simplistic solution would be adding

```
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}
```

in the preamble, but this doesn't really work, as the following example shows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
A one liner
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
This ends with a display
\[
0=0.
\]
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
Another one liner.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You should still have `\qedhere` in the display in order to get better spacing.

It's better to modify the definition of `proof` to remove the QED business.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
%  \pushQED{\qed}% <--- remove the QED business
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
%  \popQED% <--- remove the QED business
  \endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\renewcommand\qedhere{} % to ensure code portability
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
A one liner
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
This ends with a display
\[
0=0.
\]
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
Another one liner.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can still have `\qedhere`, but it won't have any effect, so copying code where the command has been used won't give surprises.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion how to edit the 'proof' environment! I am using it with \tag*{$\qed$} instead of \qedhere when using multline environment. There is a known issue of misaligning \qedhere in multline. One of the solutions is to use \tag*{$\qed$} instead of \qedhere, but there is an unnecessary vertical skip. Your modifications are useful to suppress unnecessary vertical skip that occurs.

Comment: I recommend also to add a negative hphantom of the right length before `\tag*{$\qed$}` to avoid an unnecessary horizontal skip.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want qed symbol in all `proof`s, use `etoolbox` and

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}}{}{}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}}{}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
This has the QED symbol.
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
This hasn't.
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
And this has it again.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Or define a new `myproof`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myproof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
This has the QED symbol.
\end{proof}
\begin{myproof}
This hasn't.
\end{myproof}
\begin{proof}
And this has it again.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]